# Plaid Oauth redirect_uri is not configured error

Tags: python, plaid

I am trying to implement [OAuth](https://plaid.com/docs/link/oauth/) with [Plaid-Link](https://plaid.com/docs/link/) but keep on getting this error on the server-side:

```
plaid.errors.InvalidRequestError: OAuth redirect URI must be configured in the developer dashboard. See https://plaid.com/docs/#oauth-redirect-uris
```

I am running my application locally (sandbox mode), I have a backend server running on localhost:8000 and the client-side application running on localhost:3005

I have configured in the developer dashboard the redirect URLs ([see image here](https://p23.zdusercontent.com/attachment/2000676/wgmFWRTE40snRSBSWoMwarOmK?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..ROpRmLWhFYUbSqjvRXpYmA.eu7Q-_mmtqwQWUiA7eKjo6k082d36JwIZA66jiWVlfkYanqz_3YCetQdym3Mi6IwG9cfkGKovbSD_Z31ag883QLGKRgTo5T9Lf2LvSVa6Rg-ACXiPSnZBQqGIPaAlwL7YCrPDMQcIM8bUVIPjjclP3QVLewiBJiorRfLgxoOBTpMHcvQ3dHgwNlo8uP-Ut39eN7ERp1_W8Y1fc2plGb70T4STPL5E63CGg0cniLqfvmXp3sJy37q92SVp1vr4I7J8EozD9d55EDsd9HEYiRiznNumVWArXfVuv9Mod0_K3Y.aBBxueVwwa2sQy7lGqCp5Q))

I am using the Python SDK, here is an example of the CreateLink call in my server:

```
response = client.LinkToken.create({
'user': {
'client_user_id': str(client_user_id),
},
'client_name': 'XYZ Corporation',
'products': ['auth'],
'country_codes': COUNTRY_CODES,
'language': 'en',
'redirect_uri': 'http://locahost:3005/landing-rc-solo/link-bank'

})
```

Would you know what's the issue here?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, since you're on localhost and just for development's sake, what I did was to remove the redirect altogether.
If this is fine for you then the error should go.

Comment: I found this error to be sufficient for sandbox only.

Comment: This is what I was looking for to get it working on sandbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't made a silly mistake like adding the `redirect_uri` to the developer dashboard for a different `client_id`, that all seems right to me. Would you mind filing a ticket with Plaid support so someone with the right access can dig into this a bit more closely?

Answer (score 0):

Please configure redirect uri in plaid dashboard as well. here is the dashboard link - https://dashboard.plaid.com/developers/api. Please make sure to have the same redirect uri values for plaid dashboard and your codebase